# Why is XMLHttpRequest returning PHP code?Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating some Chrome extension and I need to have a connection to a database. I followed a tutorial from

- [Getting Started Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)
- [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

Everything works fine except when I run `XMLHttpRequest` my `responseText` is the code of my PHP.

JS from popup.js:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open(   "GET",   chrome.extension.getURL("/create.php?mail=" + mail.value),   true ); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {   if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            response.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;   } }; 
xhr.send();
```

PHP from create.php:

```
echo "something";
```

Comment: sounds like the server is not running php.... looking at the code, looks like you are expecting the extension to run php, not going to happen

Comment: Browsers don't have a built-in PHP server so when you request a local extension file using chrome.extension.getURL() its contents is returned as text.

Comment: Is your server configured to run PHP and are the `<?php` and `?>` tags surrounding PHP? If you are not sure, try viewing page in browser. And, if _create.php_ is in your Chrome extension, sorry, but Chrome can't run PHP.

Comment: @wOxxOm So what are you suggesting me to do?

Comment: @AndrásElKoulali Yes there are <?php and ?>, and my server is running PHP. I think wOxxOm is right.

Comment: @wOxxOm How would you run XMLHttpRequest from chrome extension?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you're trying to fetch but anyway if it's not a local file inside your extension then remove chrome.extension.getURL.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you i managed to fix the problem.